# Visual Basic school project

Tags: vba

Visual Basic is not my primary language and I am trying to help my son with a school project and failing miserably. The program is suppose to read a file, create an ID and save it to disk. Everything works fine except for the last 2 procedures, determine the minimum swim time, (It does that) but I am trying to assign the firstName of the user to the fastestSwimmer and in the last procedure display the winner and min time.

the file it is reading is just a text file with formatted as FirstName,Surname,Age and Gender.
My fastest Swimmer is always passing a null reference to the method. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

this is the whole program:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub StartBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles StartBtn.Click
        Dim firstName(5) As String
        Dim surname(5) As String
        Dim age(5) As String
        Dim gender(5) As String
        Dim swimID(5) As String
        Dim time(5) As Single
        Dim fastestSwimmer As String
        Dim minTime As Single

        'Call Procedures
        Call GetDetails(firstName, surname, age, gender)
        Call CalcSwimID(swimID, firstName, surname, age, gender)
        Call RaceTimes(time, firstName, surname)
        Call CalcWinner(time, firstName, fastestSwimmer, minTime)
        'Call WinnersCircle(fastestSwimmer, minTime)
    End Sub

    'Get details from reading a file
    Private Shared Sub GetDetails(ByVal firstName As String(), ByVal surname As String(), ByVal age As String(), ByVal gender As String())
        Dim filename As String
        filename = "C:/Users/rk/source/repos/CleanFolder/SwimersChampionShip/details.txt"
        FileOpen(1, filename, OpenMode.Input)
        For counter = 1 To 5
            Input(1, firstName(counter))
            Input(1, surname(counter))
            Input(1, age(counter))
            Input(1, gender(counter))
        Next
        FileClose(1)
    End Sub

    'Create a Swimmers ID and save it back to disk
    Private Shared Sub CalcSwimID(ByRef swimID As String(), ByRef firstName As String(), ByRef surname As String(), ByRef Age As String(), ByRef gender As String())
        Dim genderAscii(5) As Integer
        Dim firstCharacter(5) As String
        For counter = 1 To 5
            firstCharacter(counter) = firstName(counter).Substring(0, 1)
            genderAscii(counter) = Asc(gender(counter))
            swimID(counter) = genderAscii(counter) & "-" & firstCharacter(counter) & surname(counter) & "-" & Age(counter)
        Next
        Dim savedFile As String
        savedFile = ("C:/Users/rk/source/repos/CleanFolder/SwimersChampionShip/competitorsID.txt")
        FileOpen(1, savedFile, OpenMode.Output)
        For counter = 1 To 5
            PrintLine(1, swimID(counter))
        Next
        FileClose(1)

    End Sub
    ' Gets the race times by input box
    Private Shared Sub RaceTimes(ByRef time As Single(), ByRef firstName As String(), ByRef surname As String())

        For counter = 1 To 5
            time(counter) = InputBox(" Please enter the swim times for " & firstName(counter) & " " & surname(counter))
        Next
        'MsgBox(time)

    End Sub
    'This will calculate the winner
    Private Sub CalcWinner(ByRef time As Single(), ByRef firstName As String(), ByVal fastestSwimmer As String, ByRef minTime As Single)
        'MsgBox(time(1))
        minTime = time(1) And fastestSwimmer = firstName(1)
        For counter = 2 To 5
            If time(counter) < minTime Then
                minTime = time(counter) And fastestSwimmer = firstName(counter)
            End If
        Next
        'MsgBox(minTime)
    End Sub

    ' Displays winner of the race to the winners circle, Gold medal will be sent by mail!
    Private Sub WinnersCircle(ByRef fastestSwimmer As String, ByRef minTime As Single)
        ListBox1.Items.Add("Congradulations " & fastestSwimmer & " you are the winner your time was " & minTime & " seconds. A new world record!")
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Sub calls like this `Call CalcSwimID(swimID, firstName, surname, age, gender)` 1) don't need Call and 2) don't need () i.e. just use CalcSwimID swimID, firstName, surname, age, gender

Answer (score 2):

In the CalcWinner method you use AND in the wrong way:

```
Private Sub CalcWinner(ByRef time As Single(), ByRef firstName As String(), ByVal 
fastestSwimmer As String, ByRef minTime As Single)
    'MsgBox(time(1))
    minTime = time(1) 
    fastestSwimmer = firstName(1)
    For counter = 2 To 5
        If time(counter) < minTime Then
            minTime = time(counter) 
            fastestSwimmer = firstName(counter)
        End If
    Next
    'MsgBox(minTime)
End Sub
```

When you write

```
minTime = time(1) And fastestSwimmer = firstName(1)
```

VB will ADD the first time ( time(1)) and fastestSwimmer = firstName(1) which is 0 because fastestSwimmer is not equal to firstName(1) so that evaluates to 0

Comment: Thanks very much. worked perfectly. My son thanks you, he may pass.

Comment: Last piece of the puzzle trying to finger out how to sort out how to tally female swimmers and male swimmers. I get three female swimmers but it is giving me them after clicking the msgBox 3 times.